# InfoPath: Query for multiple values in one query field

Tags: infopath

I have a form built in InfoPath 2010 that has multiple check box fields for querying with predetermined values. The problem I am running into though is that I cannot seem to query for multiple values.

Example:

I'd like to query for String 1 and String 2 against Field 1.

My understanding of SQL is that it would simply be written as:

```
WHERE Field_1 = 'String 1' OR Field_1 = 'String 2'
```

Is there a way to reproduce this in a query field?

I've tried S1 + S2, S1 %OR% S2, brackets, parens, single and double quotes. I must be missing something, right?

If you need any additional information, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unfortunately, InfoPath doesn’t have that ability when querying data connections. You can set multiple query fields with one value, but you can’t set one query field with multiple values."
--Clayton Cobb